# Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line - node

Tags: docusignapi

I have cloned this repo (https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node) and believe I have entered all required keys and codes. But, when I try to authenticate with JWT I get this error:

````
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:105:29)
    at Object.sign (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\node_modules\jwa\index.js:152:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\node_modules\docusign-esign\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:189:16)
    at generateAndSignJWTAssertion (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\node_modules\docusign-esign\src\ApiClient.js:62:16)
    at exports.requestJWTUserToken (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\node_modules\docusign-esign\src\ApiClient.js:890:19)
    at _DsJwtAuth._getToken [as getToken] (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:85:33)
    at log (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:174:33)
    at _DsJwtAuth.DsJwtAuth.login (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:184:5)
    at commonControllers.login (C:\Users\BrownJ3\Documents\repos\code-examples-node\lib\commonControllers.js:36:16) {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'get_name',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE```
````

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What this typically means is that the PEM file is missing the indicator that the key portion has begun.

PEM files are structured like this:

```
Intitial Data to be processed

-----Begin <Type>-----

Key Information

-----End <Type>-----
```

The standard for these files can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468

Can you confirm if the -----Begin / End lines are present are present in the PEM file you're using? Please don't post the actual file here, if they are present in the PEM we're going to want to have you open a support case with DocuSign so we keep any necessary private data for troubleshooting private.

Comment: Now I use the PEM file instead of the CRT and it works ...

Comment: I have the startline but still gets the error.
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: If you end up here and this answer doesn't help you, consider ensuring that the file you are reading is accessible (i.e. no perms issues)

Comment: I have a windows machine,Where do I find this PEM file?

Answer (score 22):

If you indeed have valid structure of PEM as @Matt King DS suggested, but you still get this error, it is likely that new lines are causing error.

If you are using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) then from documentation:

> Multiline values
>
> If you need multiline variables, for example private keys, those are now supported (>= v15.0.0) with line breaks:
>
> ```
> PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> ...
>
> Kh9NV...
>
> ...
>
> -----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can double quote strings and use the \n character:
>
> ```
> PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nKh9NV...\n-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY---
> ```

##### AWS lambda

I also encountered this error in AWS lambda. Here above approach didn't work for me. I had to have env variable in lambda without double quotes, with \n instead of new lines and in code I had to replace \n by \n, like this:

```
process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

Comment: Saved my life, thanks. Especially lambda part. It's valid for ELB backed NodeJS(NestJS) in my case as well. Private key strings needs to be replaced by \\n. Non of the container or datadog logs are showing this.

Comment:  for AWS suggestion, saved my day

Comment: Same for me with GitHub Actions using PEM in secrets ‍♂️

Comment: Doing the replacement is also necessary for Vercel.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, same for Heroku env var. No quotes, replace newlines

Answer (score 20):

You can validate your certificate here: https://www.sslchecker.com/certdecoder.

In my case, I pasted wrongly that missed one dash:

```
- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
+ ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Please note the first five dashes are critical.

### Caution

If you don't want to paste into an unknown site, you can try the following command instead, thanks to @Adrian Gonzalez:

```
openssl x509 -in <cert-name>.pem -noout -text
```

Comment: i am a bit concerned using an unknown site to paste a sensitive private key into it, there is no guarantee of them not to abuse it. but please do correct me if i am wrong on this

Comment: Yeah do not use this, you can try this instead in your local machine to verify its a valid certificate, it will output the same info as the website.

'openssl x509 -in <cert-name>.pem -noout -text'

Comment: If it were a certificate, it wouldn't be sensitive, but the Q was about [nodjes.crypto.Sign.sign](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/crypto.html#signsignprivatekey-outputencoding) which takes a privatekey, and (@AdrianGonzales) `openssl x509` won't work on a privatekey, nor will that website (although some others will, like lapo.it/asn1js); `openssl pkey [-noout] [-text]` will, and there are other subcommands that work for _some_ keys but not all.

Answer (score 18):

If using docker, I have some observations.

1. Try to make `.env` values plain text. Not string literal.
2. When getting the item to code, replace `'\\n'` with `'\n'`

Comment: I wish I could upvote every time this helps me.

Answer (score 5):

If you have this problem with Angular CLI then ensure that your ssl key paths are valid.

Had the same problem when running :

`ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert ./ssl/server.crt --ssl-key ./ssl/server.key`

and it turned out my paths were invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by just running the following lines of code. This can be run anywhere in order to turn the normal `\n` into actual newlines '\n'

```
jWtstring = 'your_JWT_string'
jWtstring.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

After you get the newly line-entered JWT key, you can paste it to SSM or perform the next steps as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete .nprm from  -->

C:\Users{username}

then it will works fine

Answer (score 1):

For the angular version 14.2.8 use following commands.

ng serve --ssl "Your_project_name" --ssl-key "path_of_key" --ssl-cert "path_of_your_certificate"

Example:-if your key and certificate on a same drive C://your_key or C://your_certificate

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')


https.createServer(
    {    
        key:fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    }
).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

you need to  load the file key.pem  before initialize to the "key: key.pem" with readFileSync that belongs to fs module

https.createServer:- https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener
fs.readFileSync:- https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs/

Comment: Please, use link formatting: `[link](url)`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
 const key = new NodeRSA({ b: 512 });
    let keypair = {
        private: key.exportKey(),
        public: key.exportKey("public")
    };
```

this private key at the time of signing token with RSA

Answer (score -2):

if you just using it as sandbox project you can use: (without private key)

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
```

if not as sandbox, you have to generate a privteKey.

you can see it on jsonwebtoken docs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Answer (score -2):

I have exactly the same issue on my M1 Mac Pro.

Solved my problem by:

1. Search for your .npmrc file and delete it.
   `sudo find ~ -type f -name`
   `'*npmrc' rm -rf /Users/<user>/.npmrc`
2. Do some classics like: `npm cache verify` `npm cache clear --force`
3. Finally use the `npm install`